# Permission error while creating LISTENER in AOAG setup

Tags: sql-server, listener

I know this is more of a NETWORK-related question, but you may have encountered this. We are setting up AOAG with 1 primary and 2 secondary nodes.  When configuring LISTENER with 3 unassigned private IPs, we face an error in creating LISTENER. Looks like it is related to PERMISSION.  The AD account we configured has ADMIN privileges on the 3 nodes.

Below is what the log of FAILOVER CLUSTER Manager shows. Could you direct us to few leads to resolve this issue please?

- The cluster identity 'AOAG-TST-CLUS$' has Create Computer Objects permissions. By default all computer objects are created in the same container as the cluster identity 'AOAG-TST-CLUS$'.
- The quota for computer objects has not been reached.
- If there is an existing computer object, verify the Cluster Identity 'AOAG-TST-CLUS$' has 'Full Control' permission to that computer object using the Active Directory Users and Computers tool.

Below are the Error screen shots while configuring LISTENER.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the cluster logs, it'll tell you why `get-clusterlog`

Comment: Let me have the team check this out. Thanks Sean